# Creating multiple panels in a frame?

Tags: java, user-interface, methods, panel

I am trying to draw fish at whatever location the user enters, but it will either say

```
drawFish.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
    outer.add(sPanel1);
```

Or

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Container.java:483)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1084)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:410)
at drawFish.main(drawFish.java:38)
```

I was thinking that I need to make a new panel for each fish, but how do I make a loop to create multiple panels? If that is even the problem? Also, I am supposed to use a method that takes an x and a y coordinate so the user can change the location of a fish, and draw a number of fish at different locations. But that's not what I'm doing. I've tried to make a method including the questions of x and y, but then it says that the variables aren't public and thus can't be used in the paint method. I would appreciate explanations for everything, because I want to comprehend everything that I am doing.

```
public class drawFish extends JPanel {

int x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the x location of the fish? "));
int y = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What is the y location of the fish? "));
int w = 200;
int h = 100;
int a = x + 20;
int b = y + 30;
int d = 50;

public drawFish() {
  setPreferredSize(
        new Dimension(400,400));
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
  g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
  g.fillOval(x, y, w, h);
  g.fillOval((w-5), y, d, h);
  g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
  g.fillOval(a, b, 25, 25);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  MyFrame frame1 = new MyFrame("Drawing Fish");
  JPanel outer = new JPanel();

  int fn = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many fish would you like to draw? "));

  for(int i=0; i<fn; i++){
     drawFish sPanel1 = new drawFish();
  }

  outer.add(sPanel1);
  frame1.add(outer);
  frame1.pack(); 
  frame1.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- Don't make many JPanels, just make one drawing JPanel.
- Create a Fish class that is not a JPanel nor a component, but has a `draw(Graphics g)` method so that can draw itself at its current location when asked to.
- Give your JPanel an `ArrayList<Fish>` and fill the list with Fish objects.
- In your JPanel's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method (not the paint method), loop through the ArrayList calling `draw(g)` on each Fish object it contains.
- Be sure to call `super.paintComponent(g)` as the first line of your drawing JPanel's `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method so that old drawings will be erased.
- Your for loop logic is off. If you're going to create objects inside of a for loop, you need to add them to something *from inside of the loop*. Else all you're dong is creating objects and discarding them, never to use them.
- You will want to learn and stick with Java naming conventions. Class names, such as DrawFish, should start with an upper-case letter, and methods and variables with a lower-case letter.

Answer (score 0):

sPanel1 variable's scope finishes as soon as you get out of loop.

Therefore replace

```
for(int i=0; i<fn; i++){
   drawFish sPanel1 = new drawFish();
}

outer.add(sPanel1);
```

with

```
for(int i=0; i<fn; i++){
    drawFish sPanel1 = new drawFish();
    outer.add(sPanel1);
}
```

Now all panels will be added.

Also consider using a LayeredPane.
Hope this helps.